# Problem with hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto in a migration

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, hbm2ddl

I have migrated a spring-boot project from MySQL to SQL Server. I don't have the necessary roles to use hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = update.
How can I update without having access to sysadmin?

I need to update because I can't lose the records

```
2021-07-21 | 13:30:17.660 |  INFO | main                 | o.h.t.h.SchemaUpdate      | HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
2021-07-21 | 13:30:17.692 |  WARN | main                 | .e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper | SQL Error: 229, SQLState: S0005
2021-07-21 | 13:30:17.692 | ERROR | main                 | .e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper | The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'sequences', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.
2021-07-21 | 13:30:17.692 |  WARN | main                 | ddedWebApplicationContext | Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
2021-07-21 | 13:30:17.692 |  INFO | main                 | o.a.c.c.StandardService   | Stopping service [Tomcat]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are invoking hbm2ddl but you can specify an output file and then apply these statements manually. You can configure this through the `javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target` parameter. See the documentation for details: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-hbmddl